# How to use configuration files(or variables) in js file which are defined under public directory in zend

Tags: javascript, zend-framework2, config, php

I want to use some important variables in some of my js files like fb, twitter access keys so I defined a config.ini file under config folder in zend. I am able to read these config variables in all my controller and models using INI reader but I don't know how to read these variables in my js files. Is there any other method to define config variables for js files ?
My js files are located under public folder. To read these variables in index.phtml of any module I am using view model to return these variables from controller and then use php to read these vaiables in phtml file. Is there any better method to read these vaiables in phtml file ?

```
$reader = new Ini();
$data   = $reader->fromFile('config/config/config.ini');
```

I am using this code to read my config.ini file and its working fine.

Comment: Remember that the javascript runs on the browser and cannot access files on the server. You will either have to create a javascript script fragment that contains these parameter in a javascript format, or write some AJAX code that requests parameters from a utility php script

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax

ZF2 (PHP) Side:

- Create new Controller/Ajax

  - Set it to empty layout
  - Enable Json Strategy
  - Add new action to Ajax cotroller e.g AjaxAction
  - Write code

public function AjaxAction(){

```
//maybe create service for that?


    $reader = new Ini();


        $reader = new Ini();

        $data = $reader->fromFile('config/config/config.ini');

        return new JsonModel(['Data' => $data]);

    }
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var url = "http://urlToyourSite.com/ajax/ajax";
$.get(url).done(function(databack){
var data = databack.Data(); // here is your ini object
});

});
```

---

InsertData to layout

- Create new Controller/Ini

  - Add new action to Ajax cotroller e.g AddToLayoutAction
  - Write code

public function __constuct(){

self::__construct(); //for parent

```
//maybe create service for that?

    $reader = new Ini();

    $data = $reader->fromFile('config/config/config.ini');

    $this->layout()->setVariable("Data",$data);

}
```

in layout:
//code

```
$data = $this->Data;
```